# Intellij Idea/Android Studio custom live templates repository for Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there a site or something where I could download custom live templates for Intellij Idea?

A time ago I saw a presentation about Intellij Idea in which the author showed a place that he he download a custom live templates for JUnit tests. But I don't remember where it was.

For now I would like to use templates for Junit and some others.